# How can I find bytes with $regex in Mongodb?

Tags: regex, mongodb, byte

My document:

```
{'name': 'demo',
  'data': [
    {'title': 'first', 'content': b'root'},
    {'title': 'second', 'content': b'address mapping'},
  ]
}
```

Using motor in Python:

```
collection.find({'data.title': {'$regex': 'fir'}}, {'data.$': 1})
```

I got the result expected.
But when I try it with:

```
collection.find({'data.content': {'$regex': b'addr'}}, {'data.$': 1})
```

I got **'$regex has to be a string'** error.

Answer (score 0):

That way is not allowed to put $regex in $in operator.

If you want to put regular expression object in $in operator, you have to use JavaScript regular expression object, for example:

```
collection.find({"data.content": {$in: [/abc/, /123/]}})
```

`val` in `/val/` is constant string, not the variable as you defined above.

or best you have a separate method for this regex.

```
function escapeRegExp(string) {
  return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'); // $& means the whole matched string
}
```

then query like

```
{ '$regex': escapeRegExp(searchString) }
```

Comment: Is there any way to convert the bytes to string? I want to search the content with regex

Comment: No. Based on documentation. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/